# Create Horizontal Timeline With React

Tags: reactjs, timeline

I want to create the following (attached link) horizontal Timeline (filled with `Date()` types) using React

[Horizontal timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsgtu.png)

What's the best npm library / tool to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entrely familiar with the package, but it should be doable using a simplified version of [react-calendar-timeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar-timeline) with only one row and without headers and labels.

Comment: @Sam please upvote my answer if you found it useful

Comment: it is useful, but i can't upvote for now but in case no other answer is made to my question i will accept yours

Comment: Hey Karl, please help me out. I'm trying to use something similar for my own project. I'm using this "https://github.com/sherubthakur/react-horizontal-timeline" but i'm getting one error "Line 13:22:  'HorizontalTimeline' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef". I've installed it correctly. Please help me.