# How to create a horizontal timeline in React

Tags: reactjs

There are two questions already on Stackoverflow:

1. [Create Horizontal Timeline With](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439257/create-horizontal-timeline-with-react)
2. [React How to create responsive horizontal timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610211/how-to-create-responsive-horizontal-timeline)

None of them have any accepted answer. And also my question is specifically related to [react-horizontal-timeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-timeline).

I'm creating my personal portfolio and I wish to show my education/college journey.

The author has given the code:

```
const VALUES = [ /* The date strings go here */ ];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: 0, previous: 0 };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Bounding box for the Timeline */}
        <div style={{ width: '60%', height: '100px', margin: '0 auto' }}>
          <HorizontalTimeline
            index={this.state.value}
            indexClick={(index) => {
              this.setState({ value: index, previous: this.state.value });
            }}
            values={ VALUES } />
        </div>
        <div className='text-center'>
          {/* any arbitrary component can go here */}    
          {this.state.value}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Since I'm coming from `Angular` and `MVC frameworks`, I didn't understand what this `HorizontalTimeline` is doing there. Is there anything I need to import? I'm asking this because the code is giving this error:

> Line 13:22:  'HorizontalTimeline' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Looks like the compiler is not able to recognize `HorizontalTimeline`.

And also I would like to have it as a separate component for example `<MyTimeline>` or so. Why would I clutter my *App.js*. Hope I was able to explain. Please pitch in.

Comment: You gotta import the component

Comment: Yes sure, but from where? `import { HorizontalTimeline } from '?????'`

Comment: @Tanzeel: A decent IDE would be able to find it for you if you've done an `npm install` on the package.  Looking at [the vendor's demo code](https://github.com/sherubthakur/react-horizontal-timeline/blob/master/demos/demo-swipeable-views/HorizontalTimelineContent.js) They just import it from their source code: `import HorizontalTimeline from '../../src/Components/HorizontalTimeline';`  Importing it from the package might be a guessing game, it looks like the vendor's samples and docs don't cover that.  You might just try importing it from the package name itself.

Comment: @David, you're right. but my VSCode is not suggesting anything. Also when i tried to do it manually, the compiler is saying: `Module not found: You attempted to import ../../src/Components/HorizontalTimeline which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

Comment: P.S I've installed it using `npm i react-horizontal-timeline` as mentioned in the readme.

Comment: @Tanzeel: My best guesses then would be `import HorizontalTimeline from 'react-horizontal-timeline';` or `import { HorizontalTimeline } from 'react-horizontal-timeline';`  The root of the problem here is a poorly incomplete example provided by the vendor.

Comment: The first one without braces i.e. `import HorizontalTimeline from 'react-horizontal-timeline';` worked. Though it compiled with some warnings (hope my QA team is ok with this). But yes, solution worked. Please post it as an answer so that i can accept it. Thanks David.

Comment: @Tanzeel import HorizontalTimeline from 'react-horizontal-timeline'; works because if you look at the source code you can see that the HorizontalTimeline component is a default export (meaning you don't need the curly brace import). When you use an ES6 import and it doesn't start with ./ or ../ it means you are looking within the node_modules folder to find the package to import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the component.

Unfortunately [the vendor's documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-timeline) doesn't include the `import` statement.  Further unfortunately still, [the vendor's demo](https://github.com/sherubthakur/react-horizontal-timeline/blob/master/demos/demo-swipeable-views/HorizontalTimelineContent.js) imports it directly from their source code.  Which is fine if you're using their source code, but useless if you're installing their `npm` package.

Unless the IDE can find the import for you (VS Code *should* be able to, but anything could be preventing that) then best guesses would be:

```
import HorizontalTimeline from 'react-horizontal-timeline';
```

or:

```
import { HorizontalTimeline } from 'react-horizontal-timeline';
```

Comment: accepted this answer after unit testing. no more discussion required.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this timeline component if you are interested. I think it's better for your need and also has much more clear documentation and a better horizontal mode.
[react-chrono](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chrono)

Here is an example of a responsive timeline using the react-chrono component. I have also added some code that will automatically change to the vertical mode which is better for mobile view.

```
import React from "react";
import { Chrono } from "react-chrono";

class EducationTimeline extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { matches: window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const handler = (e) => this.setState({ matches: e.matches });
    window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").addEventListener("change", handler);
  }

  render() {
    const items = [
      {
        title: "example",
        cardTitle: "example",
        cardSubtitle: "example",
        cardDetailedText: "example",
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div style={{ width: "500px", height: "400px" }}>
        <Chrono
          items={items}
          mode={this.state.matches ? "HORIZONTAL" : "VERTICAL"}
          slideShow={false}
          itemWidth={"250"}
          hideControls={true}
          cardHeight={100}
          borderLessCards={true}
          theme={{
            primary: "#01bf71",
            secondary: "#010606",
            cardBgColor: "#f7f8fa",
            cardForeColor: "#010606",
            titleColor: "#fff",
          }}
        ></Chrono>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EducationTimeline;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30279619)

Comment: I have added an example of react-chrono component.